# How to get substrings from strings

Tags: java, string

I have two strings

---

```
 1. "151.909 KB"
 2. "151.0"
```

---

In both cases I want to cut everything that comes after the period. The expected result is the following:

---

```
 1. "151"
 2. "151"
```

Comment: Don't `cut` it. `substring` it ;)

Comment: and If I'll upload over 999 kb, I'll have in result 1.1 Mb, so what then?

Comment: Please, don't just ask for something. Provide what you've tried so far, and show us you've actually had a go at trying to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: Thx, it works :) Will accept in 10 min, can't accept ur answer right now

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = "150.23121KB";
String[] requiredString = str.split("\\.");
System.out.println(requiredString[0]);
```

Comment: `split` takes a regex.... you should quote the dot.. Your current code will split according to everything, resulting with an array of each char.

Comment: Right..forgot that :)

Answer (score 2):

For this use [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the character sequence represented by this String object, then the index (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned. For values of ch in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF (inclusive), this is the smallest value k such that:

Combined with with [`String.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

## Result

```
s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = result.split("\\.")[0];
```